# creating multiple nodes with properties in json in neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j

I am a newbie in Neo4j and facing a small problem.

I created around 5000 router nodes with its ipaddress property set to specific ip.
Now I have around 5000 more interfaces and needs to create their nodes. I am using json and rest api for that in c++.

Every interface has a Routerip property and if the routerip matches the ipaddress of the router node that is already created I need to create that interface.

I have used this 
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-cypher.html#rest-api-create-mutiple-nodes-with-properties link to create my routers.
Now I want to use the same method in order to create my interfaces.
Is there a way wherein I can do so passing array of properties as paramaters in the cypher query and check for the router present to create my interface?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this. Breaking it down into steps:

- For each interface, find the matching router
- Create the interface & connect the interface to that router

That would look something like

```
MATCH (router:Router)
WHERE router.ipaddress = props.RouterIp
CREATE (n:Interface { props } )-[:CONNECTED_TO]->(router)
```

Comment: and don't forget to create an index or constraint for fast lookups `create index on :Router(ipaddress)`

Comment: Hi,

When I try to execute the query above using curl it gives error saying
"props not defined ".

Comment: @Nipun, then you haven't sent in the parameters as per the example you link to in your question.

Comment: When I do this
Create (R:Router {props})
return R;

It works like a charm but when I do this
match (R:Router)
where R.ipaddress <> props.ipaddress
create (R1:Router {props})
return R1

It says props not defined. Can someone please post an example where he has used a specific property from the array of properties in parameters in json.

Comment: Hey When I try to run this simple query it gives me java exception

Answer (score 0):

Hey When I try to run this simple query as above it gives me java exception

```
{
   "params" : {
      "props" : [
         {
            "LocalAsNumber" : 0,
            "NodeDescription" : "10TiMOS-B-4.0.R2 ",
            "NodeId" : "10.227.28.95",
            "NodeName" : "BLR_WAO_SARF7"
         }
      ]
   },
   "query" : "MATCH (n:Router) where n.NodeId = {props}.NodeId  RETURN n"}
```

"message" : "The statement has been closed.",
  "exception" : "BadInputException",
  "fullname" : "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.BadInputException",
  "stacktrace" : [ "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.exceptionOnHasNext(RepresentationExceptionHandlingIterable.java:50)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.ExceptionHandlingIterable$1.hasNext(ExceptionHandlingIterable.java:46)", "org.neo4j.helpers.collection.IteratorWrapper.hasNext(IteratorWrapper.java:42)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.ListRepresentation.serialize(ListRepresentation.java:71)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.Serializer.serialize(Serializer.java:75)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingSerializer.putList(MappingSerializer.java:61)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.CypherResultRepresentation.serialize(CypherResultRepresentation.java:83)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.MappingRepresentation.serialize(MappingRepresentation.java:41)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.assemble(OutputFormat.java:215)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.formatRepresentation(OutputFormat.java:147)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.response(OutputFormat.java:130)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.repr.OutputFormat.ok(OutputFormat.java:67)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:101)", "java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:132)", "org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)" ],