# Neo4j and json creating multiple nodes with multiple params

Tags: neo4j, jsoncpp

I tried many things but of no use. 
I have already raised a question on stackoverflow earlier but I am still facing the same issue.
Here is the link to old stackoverflow question
[creating multiple nodes with properties in json in neo4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22704821/creating-multiple-nodes-with-properties-in-json-in-neo4j/22712715?noredirect=1#comment34882132_22712715)

Let me try out explaining with a small example 
This is the query I want to execute

```
{
   "params" : {
      "props" : [
         {
            "LocalAsNumber" : 0,
            "NodeDescription" : "10TiMOS-B-4.0.R2 ",
            "NodeId" : "10.227.28.95",
            "NodeName" : "BLR_WAO_SARF7"
         }
      ]
   },
   "query" : "MATCH (n:Router) where n.NodeId = {props}.NodeId  RETURN n"}
```

For simplicity I have added only 1 props array otherwise there are around 5000 props. Now I want to execute the query above but it fails. 
I tried using (props.NodeId}, {props[NodeID]} but everything fails.
Is it possbile to access a individual property in neo4j?

My prog is in c++ and I am using jsoncpp and curl to fire my queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do `{props}.nodeId` in the query then the `props` parameter must be a map, but you pass in an array. Do

```
"props" : {
        "LocalAsNumber" : 0,
        "NodeDescription" : "10TiMOS-B-4.0.R2 ",
        "NodeId" : "10.227.28.95",
        "NodeName" : "BLR_WAO_SARF7"
 }
```

You can use an array of maps for parameter either with a simple `CREATE` statement.

```
CREATE ({props})
```

or if you loop through the array to access the individual maps

```
FOREACH (prop IN {props} | 
    MERGE (i:Interface {nodeId:prop.nodeId})
      ON CREATE SET i = prop
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this query string work for you?

```
"MATCH (n:Router) RETURN [p IN {props} WHERE n.NodeId = p.NodeId | n];"
```